Graylog sidcar file config packetbeat problem
"Hi everyone,
I'm having a problem with the Packetbeat collector in the Graylog Sidecar. It doesn't run at all with this configuration."
Needed for Graylog
fields_under_root: true
fields.collector_node_id: ${sidecar.nodeName}
fields.gl2_source_collector: ${sidecar.nodeId}
path:
data: C:\Program Files\Graylog\sidecar\cache\packetbeat\data
logs: C:\Program Files\Graylog\sidecar\logs
tags:

windows
packetbeat.interfaces:
device: 0
packetbeat.protocols:
http:
ports: [80, 8080, 8000, 5000, 8002, 443]
output:
logstash:
hosts: ["192.168.40.76:4444"]

Yes, I have reviewed all configurations thoroughly, including the Packetbeat file packetbeat.yml file and so on .
